# Recover history MATLAB code?

Tags: matlab

I have a script named `my_script.m`, which has been mistakenly replaced by another file with the same name. However, prior to overwriting the script, I have run it in MATLAB console. Hence, I have the following history.

```
>> my_script
>>
```

Is there any way to recover that history file?

---

The reason why I think it is still possible is that I do have the run history of that script in my current console. If only I had selected all the script and run it! That way I would have every command in the console history. But now, it is simply one line as above.

Comment: Since you say that you're using OS X (in a comment below) then you should be able to just use [Time Machine](http://www.imore.com/how-set-and-restore-time-machine-backup) to recover the previous version of the file as with any file. This is not really a programming question and is bordering on off-topic for this StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you had diary mode on, then everything is there:

```
get(0,'Diary')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can open the file in windows explorer, right mouse button, properties. Then check if there are any other versions of the file in the Previous Versions tab ;)

Comment: Then I think that your data is gone. You can try to undo your file overwriting (undo changes/ control+z in windows)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes matlab writes backups, the file would be named my_script.asv. Check if it exists, it's located in the same directory.

Comment: Or possibly `my_script.m~`

Comment: @ChrisTaylor I do have .m~, but even inside that, it is already the new content.